# Where is this location in Mr. Robot?

Tags: film-location, mr-robot

In the final episode of Mr. Robot, just after Elliot says goodbye to Darlene, a long shot establishes what struck me personally as quite a beautiful-looking location:

[image]

Whereabouts is this location in the real world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the actual hotel is called "West Gate Inn Nyack" in Nyack, New York, United States. You can sort of see the same shot from Google Maps though from a road behind where the camera is facing.

https://www.google.com/maps/@41.0942763,-73.9303713,3a,15y,199.09h,84.03t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sjrFkttOXdPckMOTp0qp9nA!2e0!7i16384!8i8192